# How to tap on an item of the listview appium in Python

Tags: android, python, appium

Could anyone help How to tap on an item of the listview appium in Python?

so, resourse_id is list
and on the listview some items, the difference beetween them - only index.
the list itself i'm getting by using

```
driver.find_element_by_id
```

Comment: Please provide more code and information about the software/modules you are using. Your question in it's current state is unclear

Comment: what code? i'm looking for a feature, not a code)

Answer (score 0):

finally, solved by using Xpath, like so:

find_element_by_xpath('//android.widget.ListView[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[6]')